# LabVIEW: Count how long a button has been pressed

Tags: arrays, button, timestamp, cluster-computing, labview

I'm trying to create a LabVIEW VI with an "ok button", a numeric indicator "Number of click" and an array of cluster, in which every cluster contain a TimeStamp indicator and a numeric indicator.

When the VI is running I want to keep track of:

1. When the button is released (timestamp)
2. How long the button has been pressed (in millisecond or second).

[image]

[image]

Then, when i click on STOP, i want to visualize these information about ALL the button pression in the array of cluster.

That's what I've done. I've tried to change the manner in which I create the array, and also the "Tunnel mode" in the While loop, but it doesn't work..
Can you help me? Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check my attached code and compare it with yours.
It's the simplest method, but you may also read about Event Structure, which would help to do that in much smarter way. Additionally you may want to change my code a bit to have indicators being updated in real-time instead after the exit. It's worth also reading about "Feedback node" and "Conditional" type of output tunnels. They would help to simplify the code, but I didn't use them to keep it as simple as possible!
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]